# How to use final class as type in interface (php)

Tags: c#, php

I have a stupid question. I want to learn PHP after 2-3 years of C#.

And like in C#

```
public enum SimpleEnum{
   One,
   Two,
   Three
}

public interface ISimple
{
  int Id;
  SimpleEnum SimpleType;
}
```

What I did in PHP:

```
final class SimpleEnum {
  const ONE = 1;
  const TWO = 2;
  const THREE = 3;
}

interface ISimple {
  public $value1;

  SimpleEnum $myEnum;
}
```

But the error occurred from `SimpleEnum` in `ISimple`.

Maybe is not possible but I want to ask you how to use `SimpleEnum` as type in interface ?

Thank you

Comment: PHP is dynamically typed; you can't give a type to `$myEnum`. Also, PHP interfaces can't have member variables anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible but if you need $myEnum to specifically be SimpleEnum, then just require it in the contract (interface) so any exhibiting classes will HAVE TO follow suit. You can do this by type-hinting

```
interface ISimple {
    public function setMyEnum(SimpleEnum $myEnum);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`Fatal error: Interfaces may not include member variables`... So that, you can't have properties in `Interface`s, only methods declarations, instead, you can use `abstract class` and extend it from it.

Also, in PHP, there is no strict type control. So if you want to declare property, just use `public $enum = null` and in `__construct()` init it `$this->enum = ...;`.

One more thing. If you want to be sure that `SimpleEnum` is exactly what is stored in `$enum` property, declare setter for this property `setSimpleEnum(SimpleEnum $enum) { ... }` where you store passed value to class property. Use it everywhere, where you want to change `$enum`, so that if you pass anything of class which is not extended from `SimpleEnum` - you would have a `Fatal`. Pseudo-Strict type control.

Comment: good point also sir. you can check types in PHP by using if($myEnum instanceof SimpleEnum) before processing

Comment: I choose `is_a()`... Shorter.

Answer (score 1):

As documented under [Type Juggling](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

> PHP does not require (or support) explicit type definition in variable declaration; a variable's type is determined by the context in which the variable is used.

Comment: And how to use that final class in interface ? Just simply `public $myVar` ?